# Drag & Drop UIButton from UIScrollView to UIView in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, drag-and-drop, uibutton

I Want to add drag & drop functionality on `UIButton`. Actually I have created numbers of buttons programmatically under `UIScrollView`. I add following target on `UIButton`

```
[mybutton addTarget:self action:@selector(wasDragged:withEvent:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
```

and this is the method

```
- (void)wasDragged:(UIButton *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
// get the touch

UIButton *myButton=[[UIButton alloc]init];
myButton=button;
[self.scrollView addSubview:myButton];

UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:button] anyObject];

//get delta
CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:myButton];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:myButton];
CGFloat delta_x = location.x - previousLocation.x;
CGFloat delta_y = location.y - previousLocation.y;

//move button
myButton.center = CGPointMake(myButton.center.x + delta_x,myButton.center.y + delta_y);

}
```

This code is working fine under the scroll view and button is drag & drop inside the scrollview.  Now problem is when I drag the button outside the scrollview, button disappear.
I want to drag button outside the scrollview also. How can I do this?
How can I drag button from Scrollview to another UIView? How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing code

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:myButton];
```

to

```
[self.view addSubview:myButton];
```

Answer (score 1):

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>{
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *dropTarget;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *dragObject;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView *txt_View;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *prevdragObject;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint touchOffset;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint homePosition;
@end
```

Just instead of

```
 IBOutlet UIView *dropTarget
```

just use

```
IBOutlet UIScrollView *dropTarget
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
       if ([touches count] == 1) {
        // one finger
        CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
        for (UIImageView *iView in self.view.subviews) {
            if ([iView isMemberOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
                if (touchPoint.x > iView.frame.origin.x &&
                    touchPoint.x < iView.frame.origin.x + iView.frame.size.width &&
                    touchPoint.y > iView.frame.origin.y &&
                    touchPoint.y < iView.frame.origin.y + iView.frame.size.height)
                {
                    self.dragObject = iView;
                    self.touchOffset = CGPointMake(touchPoint.x - iView.frame.origin.x,
                                                   touchPoint.y - iView.frame.origin.y);
                    self.homePosition = CGPointMake(iView.frame.origin.x,
                                                    iView.frame.origin.y);
                    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.dragObject];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
   CGRect newDragObjectFrame = CGRectMake(touchPoint.x - touchOffset.x,
                                       touchPoint.y - touchOffset.y,
                                       self.dragObject.frame.size.width,
                                       self.dragObject.frame.size.height);
   self.dragObject.frame = newDragObjectFrame;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    if (touchPoint.x > self.dropTarget.frame.origin.x &&
    touchPoint.x < self.dropTarget.frame.origin.x + self.dropTarget.frame.size.width &&
    touchPoint.y > self.dropTarget.frame.origin.y &&
    touchPoint.y < self.dropTarget.frame.origin.y + self.dropTarget.frame.size.height )
    {
        self.dropTarget.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:self.dragObject.image];
    }
    self.dragObject.frame = CGRectMake(self.homePosition.x, self.homePosition.y, self.dragObject.frame.size.width, self.dragObject.frame.size.height);
    self.prevdragObject.frame = self.dragObject.frame;
}
```

Comment: I am using this code. In this we can drag only UIImageView from UIview to Scroll View. But we can't drag UIbutton from scroll view to UIview

Comment: You can do it... how you are adding button to your scrollview ? @Rox

Comment: Programmatically... first I took Scroll View and then ImageView and add buttons on it [self.imageView addSubview:mybutton];

Comment: is your button has userInteractionEnabled ? Are you able to click the button which is present on ScrollView.

Comment: Yes I am able to click the button and also able to dragging it within the scroll view. My problem is I want to drag my button outside the scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your dragging logic up to the view that contains the scroll view and the other view. When the user starts the drag on the higher view, you determine which subview is below it. Then reassign that view (the button) to be a subview of this higher view instead of its original parent view (the scroll view). Depending on where the drag is completed, the button is added back to the scroll view or the other view is was dragged to.

Comment: How can I determine the subview and reassign that view? Can you give me more explanation. Thanks

Comment: Make use of the `UIView hitTest:withEvent:` method to find the subview at the given point.